# MacBook Air mid 2011 external Display resoltion > 1080p which adapter?

Tags: macbook-pro, display, displayport, video-adapter

I want to use my new 27" Display in full resolution. I've tried two different cheap mini displayport to hdmi adapters but they only work with a max resolution of 1080p.
Do I really need an expensive Mini DisplayPort to Dual-Link-DVI-adapter or should i try a mini displayport to displayport adapter to get the full 2560x1440 resolution?

Comment: What display are you using? What ports does it provide and what resolutions does it support?

Comment: Its a Dell U2711 with these ports: HDMI, DisplayPort with audio, DVI-D (HDCP), USB and VGA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mac OS X should detect the supported resolutions when you connect the display. Your problem might indeed be related to the adapter and cable you are using. According to the HDMI 1.4 spec, standard HDMI cables only support resolutions up to 1080i.

I suggest you use the DisplayPort or DVI port on your monitor instead, and buy the appropriate adapter for one of those.

Comment: Nice, the Display Port cable works :)

Comment: HDMI 1.4 with a High Speed HDMI Cable supports up to 4096×2160p/24 Hz.  It seems that an "active" adaptor - still not a converter - will convince the mac to output single link at high rates - search Amazon for "Mini DisplayPort to HDMI 4K" to support e.g. 2560x1440@60Hz

Answer (score 2):

Try picking up a mini displayport to displayport cable like the [Accell B119B-007J](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B004065DAC)

Using the display port was the only way I found to get the max resolution.